# Boot-repair disk failed "please change to EFI mode"

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, boot-repair

My Windows 7 broke and another commenter advised me to download bootrepair disk, which I did. Now I have Ubuntu 64-bit 14.04 installed as well. I can't boot Ubuntu at all (or Windows 7). But trying to repair this shows:

> The boot of your PC is in Legacy mode. Please change it to EFI mode. Please use Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd) which contains an EFI-compatible version of this software. ((use it from live-USB, not from DVD))

What do I do to fix it? I can't enter windows 7 or BIOS at startup, only Ubuntu live version from USB.

Comment: Most Windows 7 systems were BIOS boot from MBR drives. But was your Windows 7 install UEFI boot from gpt partitioned drive? Then did you install Ubuntu in the same UEFI or BIOS boot mode as Windows? Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. This shows both BIOS & UEFI boot screen, so you know.. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11044662/           Boot-info
I made 4 partitions when installing Ubuntu:  / ,  /home , /boot ,  swap

Comment: Your Windows is installed in UEFI mode, and Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. You also converted sda2, the Windows system reserved partition to an ext4 /boot partition. Best not to have a separate /boot for most desktops. Required for LVM or some server type installs or very, very old systems.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition Change sda2 back to unformatted and system reserved. best then to reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode without /boot, but only use Something Else or you may erase Windows. Be sure to have good backups.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was to press <kbd>del</kbd> at the Asus screen after startup which took me to BIOS? I first did something in the 'GRUB options' in 'Advanced options' of Boot-repair disk, where I disabled the boot of sta2.

At the boot menu I just 'disabled' legacy (EFI was already enabled). Then I started Boot-repair disk and a totally new screen appeared with only 1 option, the boot-repair disk. Then I had no more problems and the Boot-repair did what it should, and now Ubuntu has launched.

So I'm not sure if only disabling legacy boot was enough or if what boot repair did was needed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does your computer even get to the bootloader (I assume you're using a bootloader and not just swapping drives)?  If so, then you may have a messed up kernel.

If not, it sounds like you may have a bad BIOS.  If you never get to the bootloader, try powering down your machine, unplugging it, removing the BIOS battery, and wait 10 minutes.  Then replace the battery, plug in the machine, and try to boot.

If that doesn't fix it, you might try taking the hard drive out, and doing a 100% new install on a second hard drive.  If the new install works, then you can use the old drive as an external drive and pull your files/settings from it to put in the new install.

Comment: Yes that is not going to happen as I have a laptop. Otherwise taking out the BIOS battery would have been done ages ago.

I need a solution that does not make me go into the BIOS or windows 7. I just want to be able to boot Ubuntu without a CD or USB.

Comment: Would you be open to completely wiping Windows and all your data?  If so, just do a 100% new install of Ubuntu from the CD/USB.

Comment: I got 1 harddisk wtih C, where windows is and D, with my personal files. Worst case scenario I don't care about my windows but I want to keep my personal files. I tried to transfer them to an external disk but I've tried 2 different ones and both have "Read only" when using ubuntu live. They work on my friends laptop that has Vista no problem.

Comment: So is everything working as it should be now?

Comment: Yes it works now. I have no idea why the external disk had problems though.

Comment: If one OS is EFI, then make all of them EFI. That means downloading EFI versions of bootable LiveCD systems like Clonezilla and  Bootable Repair systems. Otherwise, you are going to have to switch back and forth between legacy boot and EFI boot.